# Snapd Install Ocrmypdf on CentOS 7.6

Tags: centos, ocr, ocrmypdf

I install ocrmypdf on Centos 7.6 that use the way "snapd install ocrmypdf". I have successfully installed completely. However, I execute the command "ocrmypdf input.pdf output.pdf" and always say "InputFileError, input.pdf cannot be found". How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the full path to `input.pdf` like `/tmp/input.pdf`

Comment: I tried full path on both source & destination file but still not successful

Comment: maybe try running with `-v` to see if you can get any more information about the problem.  Strange that a full path doesn't work..Funky software...

Comment: The problem only occurred on snapd way to install on Centos 7.6. If I use dnf install on Fedora, it runs normally without any problem.

Comment: When I run 'ocrmypdf -v input.pdf output.pdf.
It shows ocrmypdf error: argument -v/-verbose: invalid int value: 'input.pdf'

Comment: Hmmm, maybe verify that that `input.pdf` is actually a valid `.pdf` by opening it with another tool like acrobat reader??

Comment: The input.pdf is working fine. As I said, it works when I perform OCR on the DNF installed on Ubuntu .